# Error trying to create SQLite database with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, database, sqlite, permissions

I'm following the SQLite tutorial on this page http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm

But I'm getting an error when I run this code

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('test.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open
database: unable to open database file' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdb.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdb.php(6): SQLite3->open('test.db')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdb.php(9): MyDB->__construct()
#2 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cdb.php on line 6
```

So the error is that the program is not able to create the database but I'm on the inetpub/wwwroot folder and IIS has permissions over it and the turorial doesn't mention anything about permission problems. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: does the iis user have the rights to write into `wwwroot`? just having read isn't enough. you're creating a file, which means you need create/write privs.

Comment: You are not creating a database as far as i can see, you are trying to open one, does your database exist already?

Comment: No it doesn't exist. The tutorial says "If database does not exist, then it will be created and finally a database object will be returned.". Is that incorrect?

Comment: @MarcB You were right! IIS_IUSRS had access to wwwroot but not IUSR. I gave IUSR writing access to wwwroot and it worked! thanks!